# Подключиться к локальному ftp серверу через lftp

Tags: ftp-сервер

Нашел в интернете реализацию простого ftp сервера

```
Usage: ftpserver <dir> <port> [telnetmode=no], using default dir './' , port 4242
Server started and listening at port 4242, default server directory './'
```

При запуске видно, что он работает, но я не знаю как подключиться к нему с помощью lftp и вообще возможно ли это?

Подключение пошло

Вывод в терминали с lftp:

```
lftp pi-VirtualBox:~> ls
`ls' в позиции 0 [Согласование TLS...]
```

Теперь появился новый вопрос могу ли я как-то согласовать TLS через lftp, извиняюсь за ужасную формулировку

Comment: `lftp localhost`, или по имени собственной машины.

Comment: с помощью этой команды я попадаю в директории самой системы, а не в директорию указанную сервером, как будто бы я просто подключаюсь к машине

Comment: Возможно, ftp сервер уже запущен, и вы подключаетесь другому процессу сервера, Попробуйте явно указать порт и имя машины. `lftp -p 4242 pi-VirtualBox`

Comment: P.S. Тема не имеет отношения к C++, и текст в картинке - очень не поощряется. Лучше поправьте вопрос: скопируйте из окна командной строки и вставьте как текст.

Comment: @Chorkov попытался исправить вопрос, прошу прощение